# Find a basis of a subspace $S=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)\in\mathbb{R^5}|x_1=x_3=x_5,x_2-x_4=2x_1-x_3\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $S=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)\in\mathbb{R^5}|x_1=x_3=x_5,x_2-x_4=2x_1-x_3\}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R^5}$. Find a basis of $S$. Expand a basis to a basis of $\mathbb{R^5}$.

Question: How to find a basis and dimension of $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)\in\mathbb{R^5}$ without first expanding a basis?

One of the vectors that satisfies given condition is $(1,1,1,0,1)\Rightarrow$
$$        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
        x_1  \\
        x_2 \\
        x_3\\
        x_4\\
        x_5\\
        \end{pmatrix}=0\Rightarrow x_1=-(x_2+x_3+0x_4+x_5)=0$$
$1)$ Setting $x_2=1,x_3=x_4=x_5=0\Rightarrow x_1=-1\Rightarrow\begin{pmatrix}
        -1  \\
        1 \\
        0\\
        0\\
        0\\
        \end{pmatrix}$

$2) x_3=1,x_2=x_4=x_5=0\Rightarrow x_1=-1\Rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}
        -1  \\
        0 \\
        1\\
        0\\
        0\\
        \end{pmatrix}$

$3) x_4=1,x_2=x_3=x_5=0\Rightarrow x_1=0\Rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}
        0  \\
        0 \\
        0\\
        1\\
        0\\
        \end{pmatrix}$

$4) x_5=1,x_2=x_3=x_4=0\Rightarrow x_1=-1\Rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}
        -1  \\
        0 \\
        0\\
        0\\
        1\\
        \end{pmatrix}$

A basis after expansion is $\left\{\begin{pmatrix}
        1  \\
        1 \\
        1\\
        0\\
        1\\
        \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
        -1  \\
        1 \\
        0\\
        0\\
        0\\
        \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
        -1  \\
        0 \\
        1\\
        0\\
        0\\
        \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
        0  \\
        0 \\
        0\\
        1\\
        0\\
        \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
        -1  \\
        0 \\
        0\\
        0\\
        1\\
        \end{pmatrix}\right\}$

Comment: Your "basis" is wrong: $(0,0,0,1,0)$ is not in your subspace.

Answer (score 1):

This is a system of equations. You have three independent equations and $5$ variables, so the solution is 2-dimensional. More formally, the kernel of the linear map given by the matrix 
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\ 
2 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is $5-\mathrm{rank}(A)=5-3=2$.

Answer (score 1):

This is not right.  Since, notice that if you pick values for $x_1$ and $x_2$, then the values of the remaining variables are determined by the equations.  So, $x_1$ and $x_2$ are independent.  Hence a basis is
$$\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1 \\0\\1\\-1\\1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}\right\}.$$

Notice the choice of $x_1=1,x_2=0$ and $x_1=0,x_2=1$.